# Does Flutter awesome_notifications work in an apk file?

Tags: flutter, awesome-notifications

Has anyone been able to get Flutter awesome_notifications to work with an apk file on your Android phone? Everything was working fine in my emulator/simulator, but when I `flutter build apk`, then transfer the app.apk file to my phone and open the app, awesome_notifications stop working.

Have you had issues running awesome_notifications in an apk file? How did you fix the issues? Or did everything work?

Comment: What are you seeing in the logs?

Comment: I don't know how to see logs on my actual Android phone. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

My issue was NOT with awesome_notifications. I did not realize you have to add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` to your AndroidManifest.xml file to make http requests in an apk file. That's why awesome_notifications wasn't working for me, because my http requests were not working in an apk file.